# Unexpected datetime behavior

Tags: python, django, strftime

I have a Django project where I used the strftime function like this in models.py:

```py
class Email(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="emails")
    sender = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="emails_sent")
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name="emails_received")
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "sender": self.sender.email,
            "recipients": [user.email for user in self.recipients.all()],
            "subject": self.subject,
            "body": self.body,
            "timestamp": self.timestamp.strftime("%b %-d %Y, %-I:%M %p"),
            "read": self.read,
            "archived": self.archived
        }
```

However, for some reason this returns a ValueError, even though according to a documentation (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime) this is a valid format string. Once I removed all the dashes, it worked normally. Why doesn't this work? Do I need to import a module or something? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an example of your desired output and a link to the documentation you referenced.

Comment: @SarahMesser Okay, I'll add that.

Comment: @SarahMesser Added your requested information!

Comment: Those format codes with a dash, like `%-d`, are not supported on all platforms.  If you had used the official documentation from python.org, you wouldn't have been mislead into thinking that they were generally usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To @jsonharper's comment, here's a link to the official Python 3 docs: https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/datetime.html#strftime-behavior As he pointed out, that site notes platform variations are common and does not list "-" as a commonly-accepted format specifier.